# Android - split view with button on top

Tags: android-layout

I am trying to split screen in android and trying to overlay a button on top of divider

Below is the current and expected [image: Current Scenario nad Expected]

Below is my XML layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff0000" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="90sp"
            android:layout_height="90sp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/exchange"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="-45dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by aligning the layout in an ordered way or also by using the `Constraint Layout`.

**demo.xml**

```
[![<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light">

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark">

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_dialog" />
</RelativeLayout>][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the *simplest* way to take what you have and make it work would be to use a `FrameLayout` to wrap your existing layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- your current LinearLayout goes here, except for the ImageButton -->

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="90sp"
        android:layout_height="90sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/exchange"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

The `android:layout_gravity` attribute is the key here; that will float your button in the center of the screen.

While the above will work, I'd recommend using `ConstraintLayout` instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="90sp"
        android:layout_height="90sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/exchange"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

By doing it this way, you flatten everything into a single view group.

Comment: In the Frame Layout code, The two inner views don't show up and all i see is white background. Whereas in the Constraint one, the top red one take up the entire screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/topView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">



</LinearLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_dialog" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```